# Installing Davinci Reolve 18.0 on Ubuntu Studio 22.04

Tags: software-installation, graphics, 22.04, ubuntu-studio, davinci-resolve

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 22.04 on a Dell desktop, with an AMD Radeon 7100 GPU.  I have plenty of memory and storage.  I would like to install Davinci Resolve 18.0 Free, to test it out.  Blackmagic provides a .run file to install Davinci Resolve.  I could successfully install it (i.e. it successfully ran through the installer and sort of opened) on both a VM and on my Ubuntu Studio laptop.  However, when I launched it from both places, an error box appeared stating that the GPU had to be configured.  I looked at the GPU configuration in the Resolve settings, but did not see anything untoward except that no GPU was listed.  From what I understand, AMD GPUs will work with Resolve.  Do I have to install something else to run Resolve?  Thanks.

Comment: https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=56878&p=727436&hilit=rx580#p727436 will have the answers you want.